# Implicit scheme for a nonlinear PDE system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have the next PDE system:

$u_t=D_u u_{xx}-u+av+u^2v\\
v_t=D_v v_{xx}+b-av-u^2v$

Where $D_u,D_v,a,b$ are constants. I want to build or find a implicit SECOND ORDER scheme for this PDE system. I have and explicit scheme already builded but it is so unstable, and I know that implicit scheme are unconditionally stable.

How can I find/build a **second order implicit scheme**?

Comment: The standard Crank-Nicolson, as a combination of implicit trapezoidal rule and mainly midpoint approximation in x direction is order 2.

Comment: @LutzL but... Ahmmmm I just don't understand. How is the scheme?

Comment: Try google and wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method, or some blogs/tutorials http://georg.io/2013/12/Crank_Nicolson/